# How to add "empty" records for each minute without data to my query in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My query consists of a date, a time (which basically is the timestamp) and a field that calculates the comp Per hour.

```
date        time      comp/H
---------- ----- ----------------------
2019-09-10 07:01 13640,416015625
2019-09-10 07:02 8970,3193359375
2019-09-10 07:03 6105,4990234375
2019-09-10 07:04 7189,77880859375
2019-09-10 07:08 2266,73657226563
2019-09-10 07:57 163,527984619141
```

i would like to fill the gaps between the timestamps, and add a new record for each minute that didn't have any data assigned to it (for example, add record for 07:05, 07:06, 07:07) . I would assign a 0 value for the comp/h field for those records but i have no idea how to do this.

Eventual Goal is to make a line graph of the data above, in which one could visually could see downtime. 
(hence the 0 values for the "empty records")

original query :

```
select cast(p_timestamp as date) as 'datum', CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), p_timestamp, 108) as 'time', avg(((AantalPCBperPaneel*(AantalCP+AantalQP))/deltasec)* 3600) as 'comp/h'
from Testview3
where p_timestamp > '2019-09-01' 
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), p_timestamp, 108), cast(p_timestamp as date)
order by cast(p_timestamp as date) asc , CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), p_timestamp, 108) asc
```

Comment: Hmm... maybe make a "minutes" table and left join to it?

Comment: Was thinking the same, although this is the companys' SQL server and i don't have authorization to create tables... I can only edit views and run queries.

Comment: How big is the time range that you need to cover? Hours? Years?

Comment: @JacobH at this point i'll settle for the data of 1 week.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something along this code:

Fill a mock-up scenario

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;

DECLARE @mockTable TABLE([date] DATE,[time] TIME,[comp/H] DECIMAL(20,5));
INSERT INTO @mockTable VALUES
 ('2019-09-10','07:01',13640.416015625)
,('2019-09-10','07:02',8970.3193359375)
,('2019-09-10','07:03',6105.4990234375)
,('2019-09-10','07:04',7189.77880859375)
,('2019-09-10','07:08',2266.73657226563)
,('2019-09-10','07:57',163.527984619141);
```

--Filter it to one day (only to keep this simple...)

```
DECLARE @TheDate DATE='20190910';
```

--The query

```
WITH CountMinutes(Nmbr) AS
(
    SELECT TOP((SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN([time]),MAX([time])) 
                FROM @mockTable 
                WHERE [date]=@TheDate)+1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1  
    FROM master..spt_values
)
SELECT @TheDate AS [date]
      ,CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,mc.Nmbr,(SELECT MIN(t.[time]) FROM @mockTable t WHERE t.[date]=@TheDate)) AS TIME) AS [time]
      ,t2.[comp/H]
FROM CountMinutes mc 
LEFT JOIN @mockTable t2 ON t2.[date]=@TheDate AND t2.[time]=CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,mc.Nmbr,(SELECT MIN(t.[time]) FROM @mockTable t WHERE t.[date]=@TheDate)) AS TIME);
```

The idea in short:

We need a *tally table*, just a list of running numbers. I use `master..spt_values`, which is nothing more than a pre-filled table with a lot of rows. You can pick any existing table with enough rows to cover the range. We do not need the row's values, only the counter for a set. You can also read about *tally tables* and how to create them in a combination of `VALUES()` and `CROSS JOIN`. The magic here is the combination of the computed `TOP()` clause and `ROW_NUMBER()`.

So the CTE will return a list of numbers reflecting the count of minutes.

The select will use this list and `DATEADD()` to create a *gap-less* list of time values. Now we have to `LEFT JOIN` your set to see data, where there is data...

### UPDATE Some thoughts about performance

In a comment below Konstantin Surkov's answer I stated, that a counter function using a loop would be very slow. And Konstantin asked me to measure this:

Here I will compare three approaches

- Konstantins LOOP-TVF
- A simple *tally-on-the-fly*
- a table-based approach

Just try it out:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE testCounter;
GO
USE testCounter;
GO
```

--Konstantins multi-statement TVF using a WHILE

```
create function rangeKonstantin(@from int, @to int) returns @table table(val int) as
begin
    while @from <= @to begin
        insert @table values(@from)
        set @from = @from + 1;
    end;
    return;
end;
GO
```

--A simple iTVF using a *tally-on-the-fly* and `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
create function rangeShnugo(@from int,@to int) returns table as
return
with cte1 AS(SELECT Nr FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(Nr))
    ,cte2 AS(SELECT c1.Nr FROM cte1 c1 CROSS JOIN cte1 c2)
    ,cte3 AS(SELECT c1.Nr FROM cte2 c1 CROSS JOIN cte2 c2)
    ,cte4 AS(SELECT c1.Nr FROM cte3 c1 CROSS JOIN cte3 c2)
select TOP(@to-@from+1) ROW_NUMBER() OvER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))+@from-1 AS val FROM cte4;
GO
```

--And a simple static numbers table
--Together with a function using this table

```
CREATE TABLE persistantNumbers(val INT NOT NULL UNIQUE);
GO
--let's fill it 
INSERT INTO persistantNumbers SELECT val FROM rangeKonstantin(0,1500000) --1.5 mio rows
GO

create function rangeTable(@from int,@to int) returns table as
return
SELECT val FROM persistantNumbers WHERE val BETWEEN @from AND @to;
GO
```

--Here we can save the results

```
CREATE TABLE Result (ID INT IDENTITY,Measurement VARCHAR(100),TimeKonst INT, TimeShnugo INT, TimeTable INT, tmpCount INT)
GO
```

--You can use these lines to test the code *cold* or keep it out-commented to test the engine's ability of caching and using statistics.

```
--DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE
--DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
--DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

--We need a `DATETIME2` to get the moment *before* the action

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME2;
```

--And a range with a variable part to avoid any bias through cached results

```
DECLARE @range INT=300 + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Result)
```

--Now let's start: Simple counting to range x range

```
SET @d=SYSUTCDATETIME();
SELECT * into tmp FROM rangeKonstantin(0,@range*@range);
INSERT INTO Result(Measurement,TimeKonst,tmpCount) SELECT 'a count to @range*@range',DATEDIFF(millisecond,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME()),(SELECT Count(*) FROM tmp);
DROP TABLE tmp;

SET @d=SYSUTCDATETIME();
SELECT * into tmp FROM rangeShnugo(0,@range*@range);
INSERT INTO Result(Measurement,TimeShnugo,tmpCount) SELECT 'a count to @range*@range',DATEDIFF(millisecond,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME()),(SELECT Count(*) FROM tmp);
DROP TABLE tmp;

SET @d=SYSUTCDATETIME();
SELECT * into tmp FROM rangeTable(0,@range*@range); 
INSERT INTO Result(Measurement,TimeTable,tmpCount) SELECT 'a count to @range*@range',DATEDIFF(millisecond,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME()),(SELECT Count(*) FROM tmp);
DROP TABLE tmp;
```

--And - **more important** - using `APPLY` to call a function with a row-wise changing parameter

```
SET @d=SYSUTCDATETIME();
select h.val hour, m.val minute into tmp from rangeKonstantin(0, @range) h cross apply rangeKonstantin(0, h.val) m;
INSERT INTO Result(Measurement,TimeKonst,tmpCount) SELECT 'c @range apply',DATEDIFF(millisecond,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME()),(SELECT Count(*) FROM tmp);
DROP TABLE tmp;

SET @d=SYSUTCDATETIME();
select h.val hour, m.val minute into tmp from rangeShnugo(0, @range) h cross apply rangeShnugo(0, h.val) m;
INSERT INTO Result(Measurement,TimeShnugo,tmpCount) SELECT 'c @range apply',DATEDIFF(millisecond,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME()),(SELECT Count(*) FROM tmp);
DROP TABLE tmp;

SET @d=SYSUTCDATETIME();
select h.val hour, m.val minute into tmp from rangeTable(0, @range) h cross apply rangeTable(0, h.val) m;
INSERT INTO Result(Measurement,TimeTable,tmpCount) SELECT 'c @range apply',DATEDIFF(millisecond,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME()),(SELECT Count(*) FROM tmp);
DROP TABLE tmp;
```

--We repeat the above 10 times by a simple `GO 10`

```
GO 10 --do the whole thing 10 times
```

--Now let's fetch the results

```
SELECT Measurement
      ,AVG(TimeKonst) AS AvgKonst
      ,AVG(TimeShnugo) AS AvgShnugo
      ,AVG(TimeTable) AS AvgTable 
FROM Result 
GROUP BY Measurement;

SELECT * FROM Result ORDER BY Measurement,ID;
```

--Clean up

```
USE master;
GO
DROP DATABASE testCounter;
```

The results for range=300 using caching and statistics on a v2014 running on a strong machine:

```
Measurement                 AvgKonst    AvgShnugo   AvgTable
a count to @range*@range    626         58          34
c @range apply              357         17          56
```

We can see, that the TVF with the `WHILE` is much slower than the other approaches.

In a *real-world-scenario* the range used (300 will count to ~90k) is rather small. Here I repeated with a `@range` of 1000 (count goes over 1 mio), still not very big...

```
Measurement                 AvgKonst    AvgShnugo   AvgTable
a count to @range*@range    6800        418         321
c @range apply              3422        189         177
```

What we learn:

- For small-range counting the *tally-on-the-fly* seems best
- Any **counting** approach scales badly when the set size increases.
- The table-based approach is best with large sets.
- The *multi-statment TVF* with a `WHILE` loop is not holding up.

### UPDATE 2 repeated the above on a v2017

On a medium laptop with SQL-Server 2017 running locally I get the following for range=1000:

```
Measurement                 AvgKonst    AvgShnugo   AvgTablea 
count to @range*@range      10704       282         214
c @range apply              5671        1133        210
```

And we see, that with larger sets the table approach wins clearly.

**And worth to mention:** The engine tries to predict row counts in order to find the best plan. A *multi-statement TVF* is always estimated with just one row. A simple counter will be estimated with one row too. But with the indexed table the engine will be able to predict the rows and find a better plan.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or alter function range(@from int, @to int) returns @table table(val int) as
begin
    while @from <= @to begin
        insert @table values(@from)
        set @from = @from + 1;
    end;
    return;
end;

select h.val hour, m.val minute from range(0, 23) h cross join range(0, 59) m;
```

This will give you 1440 rows, for every minute of every hour of the day. You can left join it to your data to get what you want.

Comment: A WHILE loop and multi-step TVFs are something to avoid... Much better is a set based  approach.

Comment: This is set-based approach. Cross join, if you haven't noticed.

Comment: It is not. Measure it, and you will be surprised how blazingly fast it is.

Comment: Konstantin, In my answer (UPDATE section) you will find my measurements.

Comment: @Shnugo my solution, if you look carefully, is to cross join small ranges. Just as yours, really. The difference is - in my solution you don't have to explicitly type all the numbers in range. Your "performance measurements" misrepresent my solution.