# Generate X dates between 2 datetimes

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Is there a simple way to generate hourly datetimes between 2 given dates?

For example, if i'm trying to do the past 24 hours, is there a simple way to 
get each hour between
9/25/2019 and 9/26/2019?
`e.g. : 9-25-2019 1pm, 9-25-2019 2pm, etc.`

This could also expand to days -> 9-20-2019, 9-21-2019, 9-22-2019, etc.

I see there is a way to use generate_series. How would it work in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: ...because when it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: See if this helps.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135601/how-to-add-empty-records-for-each-minute-without-data-to-my-query-in-sql-serve

Comment: Sorry about that, I have tagged the DB

Answer (score 0):

```
select (DATEADD(hour, (generate_series), '9/27/2019'::timestamp))::timestamp from generate_series(1,datediff(hour,'9/27/2019','9/28/2019'),1)
```

for those interested. I got it to work via this approach. If there is a better way, let me know!

update:
this is the full code

```
with daterange as (
             select (DATEADD(hour, (generate_series), '9/27/2019'::timestamp))::timestamp  as datetime
             from generate_series(1,datediff(hour,'9/27/2019','9/28/2019'),1)
             ),

             stringdaterange as (
             select to_char(datetime::timestamp, 'Mon-dd hh:00 pm') as datelabel 
             from daterange
             )
             select * from stringdaterange
```